# Get FileSize of image loaded in HTML Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, file, filesize

Is there a way to a simple way to get the image filesize that is active in my canvas using JavaScript?

I need to manage images a user uploads so that it does not exceed a specific total file size of 10MB. I am re sizing images to 800X600 and loading them into a canvas but need to keep track of the re sized image in my canvas. This should happen client side.

Thank you

Comment: Also, I use the toDataURL() of the canvas to get the Base46 string as the end result and that is what I will need to check what the file size is.

Comment: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#MIME

Comment: you got any solution for this?

Comment: Is there a solution to this - i have tried to use atob() but the base64 version of an image is not the same size as the binary version. See https://jsfiddle.net/Abeeee/kde490x3/ which demonstrates (note it has to convert a file into an Image and onto a Canvas to get to the starting point of the test), but it shows the loaded file size vs the atob() version and it's significantly different.